# Programmable RFID Tags

Tags: nfc, hardware, rfid

I am a software developer so I have quite a lot of reading to do on hardware. My questions is this :

My goal is to create an RFID tag that has dynamic data. So I plan to use a microcontroller to be the processor and input data to an RFID module. I have did some research on RFID in general, is it actually possible to change RFID/NFC tag values via wiring instead of and RFID writer?

I really hope someone could give me some guidiance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commercial rfid tags generally have a manufacturer assigned ID (similar to a MAC address. Additionally, programmable tags have a raw memory that you can directly write bytes into sections.

When you read one with a reader, you'll get back this ID and the byte contents of the section you ask for.

A more typical use would be using the id to access a dataset stored somewhere else. Storing data locally isn't impossible though, you can also get write once types, each memory section can't be overwritten. The accrual memory capacity tends to be extremely small, like long url only.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for sharing. Is it possible that the RFID directly emits the data provided by a microchip? I am looking into active RFID in this situation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with directly emit? You have to ask for what's in a memory block.

Comment: My application saves the codes in a memory, then the microcontroller will choose which code to be used. When a third party RFID reader scans my device, it will show the RFID code choosen by the microcontroller

Comment: That's what would happen if the 3rd party reads the entire memory by default.

Comment: okay I think I have a bit more directions now. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it's helped you can you mark it / upvote as answered please

Answer (score 3):

There are commercial ICs available from different manufacturers - e.g. NXP's NTAG I2C or [ST's ST25 Dynamic NFC Tags](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/nfc/st25-nfc-rfid-tags-readers/st25-dynamic-nfc-tags.html?querycriteria=productId=SC1412).
You can connect them to your µController and share data to a phone. Most conveniently in the form of an NDEF message, as this can be read by iPhones as well.
Also the other direction (phone to µC) works, e.g. for configuration or firmware upload purposes (restricted to Android).